# How to access the text within yahoo weather's geo data nodes?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, latitude-longitude, yahoo-weather-api

I'm using the [z weatherfeed](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/example.html) plugin.

It already pulls most of the data from yweather api but I need the latitude and longitude.

The plugin gets the data for each item element like this for example:

```
html += '<div class="weatherCountry">'+ feed.location.country +'</div>';
```

However, if I try this...

```
html += '<div class="latitude">' + feed.item.geo.lat + '</div>';
html += '<div class="longitude">' + feed.item.geo.long + '</div>';
```

...it doesn't get the data for these elements.

How should I go about accessing both the `geo:lat` and `geo:long`?

Here's a live example: http://jsbin.com/sibafeke/1/edit

Comment: `console.log()` the `feed.item.geo` object, and see what array items it includes. It doesn't look like it includes `lat` and `long`.

Comment: @Charlie - It looks like it comes up as undefined. But when I log the feed.item object it actually does include lat and long values. Buuuut you just helped me figure it out. `feed.item.lat` and `feed.item.long` is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data for `geo:lat` and `geo:long` can be accessed this way:

```
html += '<div class="latitude">' + feed.item.lat + '</div>';
html += '<div class="longitude">' + feed.item.long + '</div>';
```